# SQL Server 2005 Joining Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

I have the following 3 data tables

```
Options Table
UID (pk) SID (pk) TID (pk)
--------------------------
1        20       2
1        20       3
1        13       3
1        14       4

Types Table
TID (pk) TText
--------------------------
1        Text 1
2        Text 2
3        Text 3
4        Text 4

Sets Table
SID (pk)  SText
--------------------------
13        Set 13
14        Set 14
20        Set 20
```

I am trying to get the output as follows, with only 4 rows from the options table, but with the corresponding text from the other 2 tables. My joins seems to be off tho.

The result I want is:

```
UID (pk) SID (pk) TID (pk)  SText      TText
------------------------------------------------------
1        20       2         Set 20     Text 2
1        20       3         Set 20     Text 3
1        13       3         Set 13     Text 3
1        14       4         Set 14     Text 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.Stext, c.TText
FROM    Options a
        INNER JOIN Sets b
            ON a.SID = b.SID
        INNER JOIN  Types c
            ON a.TID = c.TID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1890d/1)

**UPDATE 1**

add `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*, b.Stext, c.TText
FROM    Options a
        INNER JOIN Sets b
            ON a.SID = b.SID
        INNER JOIN  Types c
            ON a.TID = c.TID
```

Comment: hmm that's what i have, but i get six results

Comment: i found my problem the problem. It wass me. I'm using an old test database where set didn't have a PK set and had a duplicate. Setting it as a PK with unique data fixed it. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT O.UID,O.SID,O.TID,T.TText,S.SText
FROM Options O
INNER JOIN Types T ON
    T.TID = O.TID
INNER JOIN Sets S ON
    S.SID = O.SID
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b265/9)

edit: use distinct for sql server since the first query was written in mysql

```
select distinct o.*, t.ttext, s.stext from 
    options o
    inner join 
    types t
    on o.tid = t.tid
    left join 
    sets s
    on s.sid = o.sid
    ;

select o.*, t.ttext, s.stext from 
options o
inner join 
types t
on o.tid = t.tid
left join 
sets s
on s.sid = o.sid
group by o.uid, o.tid, o.sid
;

| UID | SID | TID |  TTEXT |  STEXT |
-------------------------------------
|   1 |  20 |   2 | Text 2 | Set 20 |
|   1 |  13 |   3 | Text 3 | Set 13 |
|   1 |  20 |   3 | Text 3 | Set 20 |
|   1 |  14 |   4 | Text 4 | Set 14 |
```

Comment: @Chris check this out please :) group by since you are using sql server (this is mysql) you will have to use distinct :)